# Horizontal UIScrollView using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have been trying this for quite sometime now and went through a lot of posts on SO and some video tutorials. What I want to create is a horizontal scroll view with some buttons in it, like this:[image]

My view hierarchy is as follows:

- View Controller

  - View

    - Scroll View

      - View

        - Buttons

I have set top, leading, trailing, bottom constraints to the scroll view. I have set it's width equal to it's superview, and have set it's height to 200. So far so good, for the view inside the scroll view, I have set it's constraints leading, trailing, top and bottom to zero with respect to it's superview i.e. scroll view. I have made it's width equals to the View controllers view, since that was the solution here on SO to the ambiguous width issue. It solved the issue. Now I added all the buttons and set up their constraints to their parent view. Now when I run the app, a screen like the above added screenshot appears, however I cant scroll to the last element.Any help is greatly appretiated.[image]

Comment: You have  to set the width of the ScrollView's Content view equal to the last buttons x axis + last button width

Comment: You need add an UIView inside scrollview which will act as contentView of scrollview, since you need to scroll horizontally, so your width of the contentView should be greater that the frame of scrollview, so add a height constraint same as height of scrollview, and width to a big value say 2000. Now create an IBOutlet of the width constraint that you will adjust according to your content, after setting up containerView, add all buttons on contentView not on scrollview.. and calculate the width of containerView as per last added buttons, and your scrollview should work.

Comment: Humm, i think you are messing with  content size of scrollable content of scroll view. You have to set with of content view of scroll view (that you have placed view as, super view of buttons) , Make sure the width constraints of that view matches your requirement ie equal to sum of all buttons width + sum of all spacing between buttons, You can post your project git link so that i can fix for you .

Comment: @dip: https://github.com/tejaskutal/HorizontalScroll is the link to the GIT repo, please have a look.

Comment: Fixed the problem, i am making pull request please accept , or you can directly download from ripo.

Comment: @dip: Didn't get the pull request.

Comment: Here you go
https://github.com/dipkasyap/HorizontalScroll

Let me help you if you got any issue while integrating on real project.

Comment: @dip: Great, it works. Do you mind explaining where I was going wrong?

Comment: Sure soon i got time, but in short you were adding extra constrains which were really not necessary. And Main thing you were missing trailing constraints of last button with content view.

Comment: Sure whenever you find the time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145870/discussion-between-dip-and-tejas-k).

Answer (score 5):

It's so simple.

1. Take a scrollView(Draw **top left bottom right and hight** constraint)
2. Take a **UIView** which will act like as a **container View**.(Draw **top left bottom right** constraint with scrollView).
3. Make your View Controller 1000px so that you can make your scrollView bigger and easy to watch.later on you can minimize it.
4. Now keep your button inside of it. **keep in mind that**, Every button will have top leading **width , height** and trailing if necessary. **Width & height** is important for scrollView because how big it will be depends on it.

Pictures worth a thousand word.

here is my hierarchy

[image]

And here is the Storyboard layout design.White background is basically containerView.

[image]

And here is the output.I have given some color for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: I think you missed something thats why it doesn't work. show me your storyboard layout

Comment: I have added the GIT link in the comments.

Comment: Just remove your old scrollView and make a new one. What i shared here is working perfectly.Somehow your scrollView is not working.However my approach just works fine.I made two version one is stackView and the other is just what i mentioned. here is my git link
https://github.com/junaid4058/horizontalScroll

Comment: Thanks, will check it.

Comment: For me it was also important that the last item had its trailing set

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var btnBack: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnForward: UIButton!

let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        for i in 0..<selectedRestaurant.multipleImages.count {
            let url = selectedRestaurant.multipleImages[i]

            let imgView = UIImageView()
            imgView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url as! String)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    if data != nil {
                        imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                        imgView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }



        })
                scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(selectedRestaurant.multipleImages.count), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
```

write code in btn back clicked <<<<

```
let index = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x/self.view.frame.size.width) - 1
        print("\(index)")
        if index >= 0 {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index) * self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0), animated: true)
        }
```

write code in btn next clicked >>>>>

```
let index = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x/self.view.frame.size.width) + 1
        print("\(index)")
        if index < (selectedRestaurant.multipleImages.count)  {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(index) * self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0), animated: true)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 5.1

1. firstly put scrollView give constraint to superView. Make them all what you desire.
2. Then put view on scroll view like I showed in pic. Give constraint shown below then to avoid error follow 3. step.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwzVN.png

3. Push control button and drag to the view then select Equal Height.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/91yzl.png

4. I give name to view over scrollview which name is ContentView . Be sure view size form is freeform and make width 1200 same as ContentView.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqo0v.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntW4p.png

5)Then put TableView over the ContentView and give all the constraint zero.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPbXH.png

6. This is my TableviewCell

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fxwk.png

7. And this one is the result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxBAT.gif