# Scroll horizontally in UITableView - Swift 3, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need to horizontally scroll through a list of thumbnails at the bottom of the screen that shows all the user's recently taken photos / videos.

I created a **UIScrollView** with a **UITableview** inside of it.

Is this the correct approach because I can't seem to find an override method in its superclass for scrolling direction?
Most of the topics I can find online deals with putting a UIscrollview inside a TableCell, which will not work for my specific application?

The hierarchy is:

View > **Scroll View** > Table View > **Table Cel** > Content > **PhotoThumbnail**

Below is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Comment: Why can't you use a collectionview instead of tableview?

Comment: @Brewski For horizontal scrolling use UICollectionView.

Comment: Can you show an image that what you want to achieve?

Comment: *Edited to show an example, So it sounds like UICollectionView is a better solution than UITableView in this case?

Comment: You can use horizontal stack view. Please follow this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/stack-views-intro/ Let me know if you found difficulties in it.

Comment: If you want you can check my answer on this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366920/horizontal-uiscrollview-using-auto-layout/70204124#70204124](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366920/horizontal-uiscrollview-using-auto-layout/70204124#70204124)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366920/horizontal-uiscrollview-using-auto-layout/70204124#70204124](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366920/horizontal-uiscrollview-using-auto-layout/70204124#70204124)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not really sure why do you want to use `UITableView` for horizontal scrolling which lay out there cells in vertical manner. If you want horizontal scrolling I would recommend using `UICollectionView` where cells can be added horizontally or vertically or both.
Still if you want tableview to be scrollable in horizontal direction I would suggest you to check this project to get inspiration or using it.

https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using UITableView you can use UICollectionView to achieve the desired result i.e, horizontally scrollable cells with imageView and other elements that you need.